# CakePHP get current URL without language prefix

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.3

I used [this solution](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/) for i18n of my CakePHP 2.3 website.

When user in this URL: `example.com/myController/myAction/param1/param2`
I want to give link to `example.com/eng/myController/myAction/param1/param2`
This works well with this code inside my view file:

```
<a href="/eng<?php echo $this->here;?>">English</a>
```

But when user in this URL: `example.com/fre/myController/myAction/param1/param2`
I can't link him to this URL: `example.com/eng/myController/myAction/param1/param2`

I can get the full URL with this:

```
fullURL = Router::url( $this->here, true );
$strippedURL = str_replace("http://example.com/fre/myController/myAction/param1/param2","myController/myAction/param1/param2",$fullURL)
```

But I need to make this for every language. Or I can strip first 22 characters from `$fullURL`. But they don't seem good solutions.
Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: Inside my Helper/View file I used this:

```
function getRelURL() {
  $controller = $this->request->params['controller'];
  $action = $this->request->params['action'];
  $URL = "/".$controller."/".$action."/";
  foreach ($this->request->params['pass'] as $p) {
      $URL .= urlencode($p)."/";
  }
}
```

I would be happy if you can recommend better alternative.

Comment: I think i would count the slashes and strip everything in front of the desired slash.

Comment: To make use of your Routes (and **Reverse Routing**), you should *not* generate your links using a string for the URL, but *always* use the array notation; e.g. `$this->Html->link('home', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view', 'home'));`. If you want to switch to another language, add the `lang` key to the array, e.g. `array(........, 'lang' => 'fre')` also read: [Internationalization with static and dynamic content, routing and switching](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching)

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach that seems to work well, even though I have not tested it with named parameters and all other routing features.
I created the following function in AppHelper:

```
public function urlLanguage($lang) {
    static $hereUrl=null;

    if (empty($hereUrl)) {
        $hereUrl = $this->request->params;
        unset ( $hereUrl ['models'] );
        unset ( $hereUrl ['named'] );
        unset ( $hereUrl ['paging'] );
        if (isset ( $hereUrl ['pass'] )) {
            foreach ( $hereUrl ['pass'] as $pass ) {
                $hereUrl [] = $pass;
            }
            unset ( $hereUrl ['pass'] );
        }
    }
    return array_merge( $hereUrl, array ('language' => $lang ) );
}
```

and use it in the View as follows:

```
foreach ($languages as $lang=>$langDesc) {
    echo $this->Html->link($languageDesc, $this->Html->urlLanguage($lang));
}
```

where $languages is an array with all the available language. I skipped the HTML around it the link itself.
I followed the instructions [here](http://colorblindprogramming.com/multiple-languages-in-a-cakephp-2-application-in-5-steps) for setting up the routes and language switching.